# How would I incorporate a JavaScript browser inside a JFrame

Tags: java, browser, jframe

It has become apparent to me that it isn't possible to include JavaScript with JEditorPane.

Is there another way? I must include a website tab inside my JFrame's JScrollPane, but I cannot because there is no way within Java's means.

Are there other solutions to achieve my objective. Perhaps with any libraries?

Comment: Have you looked at JavaFX?  It has a web browser component which works through web kit and which can incorporated in Swing

Comment: Problem solved. This was added. How do I close this right now before someone answers?

Comment: Feel free to either self answer (you have my permission) or delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with javaFX. It can be incorporated with

JFXPanel.
(I'll post an example up here later)